# Pseudo after align right

Tags: list, css, alignment

I'm trying to use the CSS3 pseudo :after on li elements. The issue is that the content of :after is immediately following the li content - as if :after uses text-align:left; But since my li elements use display:block; shouldn't using text-align:right; on :after move the :after content all the way to the right? It doesn't anyway.

```
.container ul li    {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(60,60,60);
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(255,255,255);
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.container ul li:after {
    content: ">";
    text-align: right;
}
```

This is a screen shot of the issue:

[image: :after not doing what I want]

I want the > to be all the way at the right, and since the content of the li changes, I can't set a width on the :after content.

How would I get the :after content to align to the right, if not with text-align?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Try [float](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp) :

```
.container ul li:after {
    content: ">";
    text-align: right;
    float:right;
}
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/surN2/

Comment: Brilliant! Now, I just need to find a thin unicode right-single-chevron... The normal > is to wide for my taste.

Comment: You can use an image in css as background image.

Comment: I am planing on using ZERO background images in this project... everything you see in the images is pure CSS.

Comment: Or u can even try by adding font family and font size to container ul li:after so that the right arrow appearance changes based on the font family and size

Comment: I decided to use ••• instead of the >, I think that will work better, but thanks for the ideas! And this is all kinda moot considering I spaced the fact that the user can't click on li:after as if it were it's own element, so I'm gonna have to use a nested div in the li. Guess it was a good exercise though, just got excited about pseudo :before and :after! XD

Comment: What about when the name of the task fills the row so the css content appears on the next line? http://i.imgur.com/PKeAPp9.png

Answer (score 6):

Hey now you can used `position` properties as like this:

```
.container ul li    {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(60,60,60);
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(255,255,255);
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
    position:relative;
}

.container ul li:after {
    content: ">";
    position:absolute;
    left:20px;
    top:5px;
}
```

and change to css properties according your design.

Live demo: http://tinkerbin.com/yXzOyDNg

If you want to right align than change `left` into `right`

```
.container ul li    {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(60,60,60);
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(255,255,255);
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

 .container ul li:after {
    content: ">";
    position:absolute;
    right:20px;
    top:5px;
}
```

Live demo: http://tinkerbin.com/rSWKxLwX

Answer (score 2):

You can use flexbox:

```
.container ul li {
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.container ul li:after {
    content: ">";
}
```

Comment: I don’t believe flexbox was a fully implemented standard 10 years ago, but this is probably handy if someone runs into the issue now. (Not sure I have that code anymore to test this)

Comment: This is a great solution now, although `align-items: center` doesn't appear to be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Use `float:right` and special `line-height` for vertical alignment.

```
.container ul li    {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(60,60,60);
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(255,255,255);
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 100%;
}

.container ul li:after {
    content: ">";
    float: right;
    line-height: 12px;
}
```